# Ansible included play task get error "failed to open a SFTP connection"

Tags: ansible

I have one playbook initiated by another using include setup as follows.

parent.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
   - add_host:
       name: "{{ item.value['hostname'] }}"
       ansible_host: "{{ item.value['oob_ip'] }}"
       ansible_user: "{{ servers.web_servers.vars.ilousername }}"
       ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ servers.web_servers.vars.ilopassword }}"
       group: ilohosts
- hosts: ilohosts 
  tasks:
    - include: collect_mac.yml
```

collect_mac.yml

```
#- set_fact: 
#    ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ servers.web_servers.vars.ilopassword }}"

- name: collect MAC address
  raw: "racadm getsysinfo"
  register: eth_info
```

The rest of the yml I have stripped out. As its few regex to grab the MAC address.

The issue is that when I run the collect_mac.yml as a separate playbook adding the headers and including the same hosts in an inventory file.

```
- name: collect mac
  hosts: hosts
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: False
```

It run without an issue. But when its ran via the parent.yml, I get the following error

```
{"msg": "failed to open a SFTP connection (Garbage packet received)"}
```

Why ansible tries to open an SFTP session, instead of SSH and run the raw command?

Comment: "add_host" is a module in a task. It's not a play. Hence it's not "one playbook initiated by another". Please follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the actual issue. Its the **gather_facts** causing the issue. As soon as I modify the part in parent.yml which calls the child.yml like this error was gone.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
   - add_host:
     name: "{{ item.value['hostname'] }}"
     ansible_host: "{{ item.value['oob_ip'] }}"
     ansible_user: "{{ servers.web_servers.vars.ilousername }}"
     ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ servers.web_servers.vars.ilopassword }}"
     group: ilohosts
- hosts: ilohosts
  gather_facts: False 
  tasks:
   - include: collect_mac.yml
```

I think this is because the server I'm connecting does not support SFTP and when gather_facts enabled it tries to SFTP the result json back to the source server.
thank you @Vladimir Botka, your comment pointed me to the correct direction

Answer (score 0):

- List the *hostvars*
- double-check the parameters are correct
- and potentially fix the parameters of add_host

.

```
- hosts: ilohosts 
  tasks:
    - debug: var=hostvars
```

For example, the playbook below works as expected.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: test_01
        ansible_host: 10.1.0.51
        groups: ilohosts
- hosts: ilohosts
  tasks:
    - raw: hostname
      register: info
    - debug:
        var: info.stdout
```

Comment: Its already there in the parent.yml. I missed copying it. Now the question is updated.